# Wire a 4 wire outlet to a 3 wire outlet

Tags: wiring, connectors

The plug on my generator is a 4 wire outlet, red, black, white, green with yellow stripe, how would I connect a 3 wire plug, I’m trying to power an electric stove in my garage, for powder coating, I don’t know how the post the pictures the generator is a Predator 4,000
3,200 running watts, 4,000 peak watts,

Comment: Change to a 4-wire cord.  It is grounded and safer.

Comment: The instructions for a 4-wire cord can be found in the downloadable  installation instructions.

Comment: Model # of the stove?

Answer (score 3):

Your 3-wire stove could have one two possible sets of 3-wires.

- Hot/Hot/Neutral - e.g., NEMA 10-30 - In this case, it is missing the ground wire, which has been required for many years but is often grandfathered (sometimes improperly).
- Hot/Hot/Ground - e.g., NEMA 6-20 This is perfectly safe. A lot of 240V devices simply don't need the 120V capability provided by a neutral wire.

In either case, the solution is the same. Replace the 3-wire plug with a 4-wire (hot/hot/neutral/ground) plug. Depending on the situation, you may end up with a missing neutral (which is OK) or need to separate ground from neutral where the cord attaches to the oven.

But there is one more key aspect - *current*. A 3,200W/4,000W peak generator can only handle around 13A continuous, 16A peak at 240V. What we don't know is how much current your oven needs. If it is designed for a 20A circuit then you are *probably* OK. If it is designed for a 30A circuit then it will be too much for the generator.

Comment: Likely will have issues during preheat when top and bottom elements are switched on. I have dealt with that by preheating on broil setting, but yes, 3200w is still a bit weak.

Comment: It's also OK to continue with Hot/Hot/Ground with a NEMA 6-30 if the sire supports it.  As you not many 240V devices stopped using the neutral a long time ago, and most modern power supplies take world voltage meaning anything from 100-250 or so.

Comment: @Bryce For typical electronics - computer, printer (except laser), TV/monitor, etc. 100 - 250 is extremely common. But a stove or oven will generally not work properly at 1/2 or double voltage, or if it does, not very well. Because it is all about resistance heat and that depends on Ohm's law. Exception: induction stoves, but those have a whole different set of complications.